# How to validate large input against mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, stored-procedures, mongodb-query

I'm getting a input CSV file with large number of rows and I need to validate each row whether they exist in a collection in mongodb. Querying DB for each row in CSV would be a bad choice. Would using "stored javascript" be any better? And how good it will be if I implement "stored javascript" through Java?

Comment: In the sentence: ' I need to validate each row whether they exist in a collection ' do you mean exits in any document under that collection?

Comment: yes. I need to verify that data in each row of CSV is available as document in a collection.